# initializing a javascript dictionary with empty arrays

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I want to initialize a dictionary with k empty arrays (keys are integers from 0 to k-1), something similar to python comprehension list:

```
data = {k: [] for k in range(2)}
```

Is something possible in javascript? if not, what would be the best way to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "dictionary"? An object? A Map? Why a "dictionary" rather than an array? (Your `for k in range(2)` suggests to me -- not a Python guy -- that your keys would be `0` and `1`, which would suggest an array...)

Comment: Yes you're absolutely right it could have been just an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, its possible to do that in just a single line in JS.

```js
let data = {
  ...Array.from({ length: 2 }, () => [])
};

console.log(data);
```

**You can also experiment it, [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-flower-zqcbp2?file=/src/index.js)**

---

## Make a function of it.

It will be easier and reusable if you make a function of it. Here the example:

```js
// traditional function
function generateData(howMany) {
  return {
    ...Array.from({ length: howMany }, () => [])
  };
}

// ES 6 function
const generateDataES6 = (howMany) => ({ ...Array.from({ length: howMany }, () => []) });

console.log("traditionnal:", generateData(4));
console.log("ES6:", generateDataES6(3));
```

### Results:

[image]

---

> **References:**
>
> 1. Spread operator: [MDN - Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
> 2. Array.from() : [MDN - Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#using_arrow_functions_and_array.from) and [W3-School - JS Array.from()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_from.asp)

Comment: Thanks for the advice @T.J.Crowder  I think you're right. And yours is also more cleaner. I'll edit it soon.

Answer (score 0):

In python

```py
>>> {k: [] for k in range(2)}
{0: [], 1: []}
```

In javascript, you should do the following:

```js
const data = {};
for (let k = 0; k < 2; ++k) data[k] = [];

console.log(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That would definitely work, but I was looking for a more functional way to do it. Upvoted!

Comment: @jenesaisquoi - [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72032527/157247) you've picked isn't really functional, it just (ab)uses `reduce`. It's mutating a single object on every call from `reduce` to the callback. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72033242/157247) is properly functional.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your phyton statement will generate the output below

```
data = {k: [] for k in range(2)}

print(data)
// {0: [], 1: []}
```

In javascript, you can utilize `.reduce()` to achieve the same result.

```js
data = [...Array(2).keys()].reduce((obj, d) => { obj[d] = []; return obj; }, {})

console.log(data)
// {0: [], 1: []}
```